# node.js TypeError:Cannot read property'replace' of undefind

Tags: node.js

[I have already added the reference,but it still tells me the error like picture 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cWyP.png)

[message of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk206.png)

I'm the new to learn node.js and don't understand the reason of it.

Comment: what does `console.log(err)` say? -- The error is on the first `.replace()`. Maybe there's an error.

Comment: yes. .replace() is the error, but ,these code are same to the book.I don't know why is error. how to use this word?

Answer (score 0):

**You are not handling errors !**
You have error in while reading a file.

```
var on404 = function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile("server/404.html", "utf-8", function (err, file) {
    if(err) return next(err); // If error than do not proceed 
    //
    // YOU OTHER CODE GOES HERE ....
    // 
    // ...
  });
}
```

FYI: No need of else as if it goes in `if`, then function execution ends with `return` statement.